# Getting value from textboxes that depends on dropdown menu then adding the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following codes. I don't know what part I got wrong. What it does is, a value will be shown in the textboxes, depending on the selected option in the dropdown. Then, the values in the two textboxes will be added. And its answer will be shown on the third textbox. The showing of values in the textbox is perfectly running, the only problem is it does not add and it does not show on the third textbox.

```
<select id="Dropdown1">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>

<select id="Dropdown2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="txt1"/>
<input type="text" id="txt2"/>
<input type="text" id="total"/>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Dropdown1").change(function(){
        if($(event.target).val() == 'A'){
            $("#Dropdown2").change(function(){
                if($(event.target).val() == '1'){
                    $('#txt1').val('10.00');
                    $('#txt2').val('15.00');
                }else if($(event.target).val() == '2'){
                    $('#txt1').val('45.00');
                    $('#txt2').val('23.00');
                }else { 
                    $('#txt1').val('30.00');
                    $('#txt2').val('53.00');
                }
                if($(event.target).val() == 'B'){
                    $("#Dropdown2").change(function(){
                        if($(event.target).val() == '1'){
                            $('#txt1').val('11.00');
                            $('#txt2').val('17.00');
                        }else if($(event.target).val() == '2'){
                            $('#txt1').val('23.76');
                            $('#txt2').val('46.00');
                        }else { 
                            $('#txt1').val('33.00');
                            $('#txt2').val('53.76');
                        }
                        if($(event.target).val() == 'C'){
                            $("#Dropdown2").change(function(){
                                if($(event.target).val() == '1'){
                                    $('#txt1').val('20.00');
                                    $('#txt2').val('17.00');
                                }else if($(event.target).val() == '2'){
                                    $('#txt1').val('23.76');
                                    $('#txt2').val('40.00');
                                }else { 
                                    $('#txt1').val('37.00');
                                    $('#txt2').val('43.76');
                                }
                            });
```

**javascript**

```
function subtotal(){
    var a = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("txt2").value;

    var stotal = parseInt(a)+ parseInt(b);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "$" + stotal;
}
```

Comment: #Dropdown2 should be #Dropdown12 as per your html.

Comment: sorry for that. edited it already.

Comment: try the answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to display it in third *textbox* so you have to set its `value` attribute, or `val` using jQuery.

Also it may be worth telling you that you've to use the `radix` part of `parseInt`. In your case it should be 10, I suppose and if you're damn sure of getting a number, you can well use `Number(a)` or `+a` which will convert it to number.

```
$('#total').val("$" + stotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#total').val('$' + stotal);
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "$" + stotal;
```

...and where do you call the subtotal() function ?...I don't see it. It should be called every time a select changes, in your 'change' listeners (you could use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function instead).

Also you shouldn't mix DOM API (getElementById(...)) and jQuery ($('#...')) I think (not really a pb but less readable).

And to get rid of your conditionnals you could use your numeric values on the value attributes of your "options", and spare a lot of if() {} else {}, or use data-xxx attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Here a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6wefo6t9/1/).

Too much eventlisteners and some logical errors.

New jQuery code:

```
$("#Dropdown1, #Dropdown2").change(function(){
    if($("#Dropdown1").val() == 'A'){
            if($('#Dropdown2').val() == '1'){
                $('#txt1').val('10.00');
                $('#txt2').val('15.00');
            }else if($('#Dropdown2').val() == '2'){
                $('#txt1').val('45.00');
                $('#txt2').val('23.00');
            }else { 
                $('#txt1').val('30.00');
                $('#txt2').val('53.00');
            }
    }
     if($("#Dropdown1").val() == 'B'){
            if($('#Dropdown2').val() == '1'){
                $('#txt1').val('11.00');
                $('#txt2').val('17.00');
            }else if($('#Dropdown2').val() == '2'){
                $('#txt1').val('23.76');
                $('#txt2').val('46.00');
            }else { 
                $('#txt1').val('33.00');
                $('#txt2').val('53.76');
            }
     }
     if($("#Dropdown1").val() == 'C'){
            if($('#Dropdown2').val() == '1'){
                $('#txt1').val('20.00');
                $('#txt2').val('17.00');
            }else if($('#Dropdown2').val() == '2'){
                $('#txt1').val('23.76');
                $('#txt2').val('40.00');
            }else { 
                $('#txt1').val('37.00');
                $('#txt2').val('43.76');
            }
     }
     subtotal();
 });
```

---

EDIT:

Forgot the subtotal function:

```
function subtotal(){
  var a = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("txt2").value;

  var stotal = parseInt(a)+ parseInt(b);
  $('#total').val("$" + stotal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Dropdown1").change(function(event){
          if($(event.target).val() == 'A'){
              $("#Dropdown2").change(function(event1){
                  if($(event1.target).val() == '1'){
                      $('#txt1').val('10.00');
                      $('#txt2').val('15.00');
                  }else if($(event1.target).val() == '2'){
                      $('#txt1').val('45.00');
                      $('#txt2').val('23.00');
                  }else { 
                      $('#txt1').val('30.00');
                      $('#txt2').val('53.00');
                  }
                  subtotal();
              });
          }
           if($(event.target).val() == 'B'){
              $("#Dropdown2").change(function(event1){
                  if($(event1.target).val() == '1'){
                      $('#txt1').val('11.00');
                      $('#txt2').val('17.00');
                  }else if($(event1.target).val() == '2'){
                      $('#txt1').val('23.76');
                      $('#txt2').val('46.00');
                  }else { 
                      $('#txt1').val('33.00');
                      $('#txt2').val('53.76');
                  }
                  subtotal();
              });
           }
           if($(event.target).val() == 'C'){
              $("#Dropdown2").change(function(event1){
                  if($(event1.target).val() == '1'){
                      $('#txt1').val('20.00');
                      $('#txt2').val('17.00');
                  }else if($(event1.target).val() == '2'){
                      $('#txt1').val('23.76');
                      $('#txt2').val('40.00');
                  }else { 
                      $('#txt1').val('37.00');
                      $('#txt2').val('43.76');
                  }
      });
              subtotal();
           }

       
           });

 
 });
function subtotal(){
 var a = $("#txt1").val();
 var b = $("#txt2").val();

 var stotal = parseInt(a)+ parseInt(b);
 $('#total').val('$' + stotal);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <select id="Dropdown1">
  <option >select</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
 </select>

<select id="Dropdown2">
  <option >select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>

<input type="text" id="txt1"/>
<input type="text" id="txt2"/>
<input type="text" id="total"/>
```

: